# SQL Server 2012 slow

Tags: sql-server-2012

I recently moved my .NET development from an older Core2Duo 2.93 GHz PC to a new Core i7-3820 3.6 GHz machine. No changes were made to the project code or database layout. Both machines use the same SQL Server 2012 Express with Advanced Services (not LocalDB).

I observe a significant slowdown of INSERT INTO commands: what used to take 1-2 milliseconds per row on the old machine, now takes 8-9 milliseconds on the new one. The only fix I was able to find was to use multiple row inserts in one command, which seems to spread the overhead of the command over many rows. As in SQL Server 2008 R2, in SQL Server 2012 the limit for the number of rows in one such command is 1000:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

However, the multiple row workaround is not applicable to all scenarios; e.g. table adapter updates that go row by row and take a long time to complete.

Has anyone experienced this problem? How would I go about resolving it?

Comment: Did you update statistics after you upgraded? Did you set the compatibility level to 110?

Comment: Also as @buckley hinted you should look at using table-valued parameters instead of table adapters. http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#TVP_in_TSQL

Comment: Aaron: can you elaborate on the statistics recommendation? I am not at expert level with SQL Server.

Comment: Statistics hold information about data distribution and selectivity in a column or columns. You can read more about updating these here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx It's one of the steps even Microsoft encourages after upgrading - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267.aspx

Comment: From Erland Sommarskog's page: "However, you cannot use the type with CREATE TABLE (it could have been nutty with temp tables!), and nor can you use it for the declaration of the return table in multi-step table functions. The raison d'être for table types is to use them when you declare table-valued parameters for stored procedures or user-defined functions." So, TVPs do not appear to be a substitute for table adapters (which are automatically-generated interface classes in VB .NET).

Comment: I don't understand - is the goal to use table adapters, or is the goal to insert/update multiple rows in a table that already exists in your database? Why can't you do this using a DataTable or a List?

Comment: uh.. are you sure you have the UNITS correct on your milliseconds? I know that there are some new datatypes in SQL 2012 that have greater accuracy when it comes to milliseconds / nanoseconds, etc.. It just caught my eye that you could have gone from 1-2ms to 800-900 nanoseconds.. which would roughly correspond to a 30% increase in performance. Just a reminder - check your units / datatypes!

Answer (score 0):

The cpu is definitely better but what about the disk io? Inserts obviously rely on that subsystem.

It happens I was just reading this article http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/05/16/sql-server-high-performance-inserts/

It seems table value parameters can increase performance dramatically

The comments lead to the following page which has some impressive numbers.

In the comments http://florianreischl.blogspot.de/2012/03/performance-comparison-of-sql-server.html

I've yet to use this myself but tvp seem the way to go to pump data from a client to sql server if you have 2008 or up.

Comment: The new machine has a 2TB 7200rpm SATA-3 "regular" HDD, while the old one has a 1TB 7200rpm SATA-2 "green" HDD. In copying large files on the same HDD, I observe 60-70MBps on the old PC and 100-110MBps on the new one. So, disk I/O should not be an issue here (if anything, it is provably faster on the new machine). Could the increased execution time of a single INSERT INTO command be a result of increased latency in the TCP/IP stack that is used for communication with SQL Server through the internal loopback address?

Comment: I think it's time to dig into SQL Server a bit deeper and compare execution plans between the old and the new server. You can use SQL Server profiler to capture all the traffic and analyze them in SSMS (sql server management studio) so there is no doubt that you are looking at the queries presented to sql server.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, writing records one at a time is ALWAYS slow.. CONSIDER - if it fits within your architecture - to write the rows to a text file and then BULK INSERT it, and your performance will go up tremendously.